# How can I pass the json data to an update view | Laravel

Tags: laravel

I store the address of a user as json in my database.

```
    $user->update([
        'address' => json_encode([
            'street_no' => $input['street_no'],
            'street_name' => $input['street_name'],
            'city' => $input['city']
            ])
    ]);
```

Now, I want to be able to view all this information in the updateView.
So, my edit function passes the user information to the view like the following:

```
public function edit(){
    $user = User::whereId(Auth::id())->first();
    return view('profile/edit', compact('user'));
}
```

And inside the edit.blade.php I have the form:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PUT', 'action'=> ['UserController@update', $user->id],'files'=>true]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('passwrod', 'Passwrod:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('passwrod', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('file', 'Profile Image:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('street_no', 'Street Number:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('street_no', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('street_name', 'Street Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('street_name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('city', 'City:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

However, the address fields like street_no, street_name and city show black.

How can I retrieve that information?

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode for that,

**Controller**

```
public function edit(){
    $address = json_decode($user->address);
    $user = User::whereId(Auth::id())->first();
    return view('profile/edit', compact('user','address'));
}
```

**View**

$address will give you details in array, then you can use these data in view like this:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PUT', 'action'=> ['UserController@update', $user->id],'files'=>true]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('passwrod', 'Passwrod:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('passwrod', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('file', 'Profile Image:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('street_no', 'Street Number:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('street_no', $address['street_no'], ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('street_name', 'Street Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('street_name', $address['street_name'], ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('city', 'City:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('city', $address['city'], ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I haved added adress specific informations, please add other user info your self. I hope you understand.

Comment: Minding sending a full snippet of what to do in the controller as well as in the view?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you model should cast the `address` field as array: (See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators)

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'address' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

This way you don't need to `json_encode` and `json_decode` your data. Eloquent will handle this for you.

Now you can use dot notation for field names:

```
{!! Form::text('address.street_no', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```